# telnet: Could not open connection to the host, on port 23

Tags: windows, telnet

I need to telnet, to localhost. I am on windows.

Once I got the error '`telnet is not recognized...`' I looked online and found that I should do `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"`.

I did, then `telnet localhost` (0r `127.0.0.1`, maybe with a port at the end), I get error:

`Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed`.

I added the port to the firewall, disabled the firewall.. run as admin..

Please help me get telnet to work! Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using telnet to a separate host entirely?

Comment: I was able to do what I needed, telnet 127.0.0.1 port (I didn't realize I had to put a space, not colon before the port). Still not sure why port 23 doesn't work...

Comment: Oh yeah I could have told you that if you showed us what you were typing! :P Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Right... I'm going to mark Richie086's answer (the only answer), since I did not know that I needed to have a telnet SERVER installed locally, I only installed a client. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a telnet server installed locally?  If not, you will not be able to connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 23.   Also, why telnet?  some specific reason?   Why not just open a command prompt considering you are connecting to 127.0.0.1 and already have a command prompt open.

FYI - I highly suggest checking out a tool called PuTTy.  It is a SSH/Telnet/Serial terminal application for windows that allows you to save connection details, set various options for your session, etc.   Best of all, it's free!